# PDF to HTML Conversion

Tags: css, html, pdf, svg

I have a client that is looking to convert their pdf files into html documents that would replace pages in his web site.

I have been looking for hours, and can not find a solution that would just give me the html and css files, only links of the html embed on there pages, and no access to place them into my webpage.

Comment: That's some very bad idea in the first place. PDF are meant to be printed. HTML pages are meant to be interpreted by a browser and displayed on a screen. I seriously doubt such a tool exists and do some good stuff anyway. And this question is NOT for SO

Comment: This tool came recommended by a friend. He said its open source so you can steal the code they use for converting and use it on your website. He did say, like Bartdude, that its a bad idea.
http://webdesign.about.com/gi/o.htm?zi=1/XJ&zTi=1&sdn=webdesign&cdn=compute&tm=17&f=10&su=p284.13.342.ip_p504.6.342.ip_&tt=3&bt=8&bts=8&zu=http%3A//coolwanglu.github.com/pdf2htmlEX/

Answer (score 2):

This isn't possible in a way that creates a nice output.  They are completely different formats for completely different purposes.  Short of making pages that are nothing but images, or absolutely positioning everything, this isn't possible.

It would be far better to re-make the document.

Ever seen the HTML generated by Microsoft Word?  Direct conversion would be at least that bad.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I was trying to see if it could save me some work, but I guess not. Thanks for the info everyone!